# Xamarin forms: How to change the label text value from viewmodel?

Tags: xamarin.forms, label, viewmodel

I want to change my label text value of the previous page when back button pressed from the new page. I use messagecenter feature from new page and redirect the code flow to the RefreshCustomerDetails() in viewmodel.

I tried like below.

```
string _fullname = "";
public string FullName
{
    protected set
    {
        if (_fullname != value)
        {
            _fullname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }
    get { return _fullname; }
}

public void RefreshCustomerDetails()
{
   //FullName = null;
   FullName = Application.Current.Properties["customerFullName"].ToString();
}

   <Label 
      x:Name="title_label"
      Text="{Binding FullName}"
      Font="Bold,18" 
      TextColor="Black"
      Margin="-20,0,0,0"
      HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
      VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

Taking the Fullname value from Local db and Bind it like above code, but no change in the name when back buttoon press. Try assign null value, that is also not working.

Any correction on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the code like below, remove RefreshCustomerDetails()
 and add **Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread** inside of **MessagingCenter**.

```
Text="{Binding FullName,Mode=TwoWay}"


MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddCustomerBySOPage>(this, "Refresh", (sender) =>
     {
       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
         {
            FullName = Application.Current.Properties["customerFullName"].ToString();
          });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, it should work. Does your ViewModel inherate from `INotifyPropertyChanged`? This is required for `OnPropertyChanged()`:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Yes MyViewModel  inherited from INotifyPropertyChanged